# Format MYSQL QUERY result

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem with my query in mySQL. I need format all the apps horizontally, not vertically.

This is my SQL table:

```
create table `data` (
    `client` varchar (150),
    `monthh` varchar (150),
    `apps` int (50)
); 
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','january','100');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','february','90');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','february','50');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','march','0');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','may','0');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','june','185');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','july','220');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE A','august','0');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE B','march','0');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE B','april','185');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE B','may','165');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE B','june','0');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE B','august','140');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE C','august','100');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','january','117');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','february','103');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','march','129');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','april','112');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','may','115');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','june','111');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','july','111');
insert into `data` (`client`, `monthh`, `apps`) values('STORE D','august','109');
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT client,monthh,apps FROM data WHERE client = 'STORE A'
```

now... for example I have:

```
client     monthh     apps
STORE A    january    100
STORE A    february   90
STORE A    february   50
STORE A    march      0
STORE A    may        0
STORE A    june       185
STORE A    july       220
STORE A    august     0
```

but I need

```
client january february march april may june jule august september october november december
STORE A 100 90 50 0 0 185 220 0
```

Can u help me?

Sorry for my bad explanation. My English is awful.

:D

Comment: Where do you want to use this data? You need to provide more info. And I don't think you can format like that with SQL. What you need to do is retrieve the data from the DB and then format/use it the way you want with the technology that you're using it for.

Comment: i need to match all the data in one table. i need to show month by month the apps by client i one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
select
    client,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'january'  then  apps end) january,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'february'  then  apps end) february,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'march'  then  apps end) march,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'april'  then  apps end) april,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'may'  then  apps end) may,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'june'  then  apps end) june,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'july'  then  apps end) jule,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'august'  then  apps end) august,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'september'  then  apps end) september,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'october'  then  apps end) october,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'november'  then  apps end) november,
    max(case  when  monthh = 'december'  then  apps end) december
from data
group by client
```

If  you need  data of `STORE A`  then  add  a  where  condition

```
where  client  =  'STORE A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
 SELECT client,group_concat(monthh),group_concat(apps) FROM data WHERE client = 'STORE A' group by client
```

Comment: almost. i need to show months separately with its applications